# Parse incoming JSON and remove wrapping boilerplate

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Within my program I'm calling an api which returns a list of users. However the result is wrapped in boilerplate like this.

```
{
  "d": {
    "result" : [ ... here the actual lsit ... ]
  }
}
```

I want to parse the result, but i cannot find an easy way to remove the "d" and "result" from my incoming json string

I started with creating my own class for a staging user entity, because the resultset does not exactly match my users entity

```
class StagingUser {
    // same props as api response per user
}
```

My thought was then to parse the useres like this

```
private List<StagingUser> parseResult(@RequestBody List<StagingUser> stagingUsers) {
    return stagingUsers;
}
```

However it would require me to get rid of the boilerplate result

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: This JSON is not valid "result [.....]" it should be either "result" : [....]

Comment: that's just a typo, but thanks @Thrasher i've added my ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use gson library. [gson-2.8.0.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/gson-2.8.0.jar)

#### Ignoring "D":

[image]

#### Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

### StagingUser:

```
public class StagingUser
{
    private String hi;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    public StagingUser()
    {

    }

    public String getHi ( )
    {
        return hi;
    }

    public void setHi ( String hi )
    {
        this.hi = hi;
    }

    public String getName ( )
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName ( String name )
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName ( )
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName ( String lastName )
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "StagingUser [hi=" + hi + ", name=" + name + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }


}
```

### JsonTest:

This is getting a json string format, parsing ignoring d wrapper, and then set the attributes to StagingUsers. Is printing everything for informational purposes

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class JsonTest
{

    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {
        String jsonInString = "{ \"d\": { \"result\" : [ \"hello\", \"Frank\", \"Provost\" ] } }";

        System.out.println ( "Printing JSON String" );
        System.out.println ( jsonInString );
        System.out.println (  );

        JsonParser parser =  new JsonParser();
        JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(jsonInString).getAsJsonObject().get("d").getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray jsonArray =  jsonObject.get("result").getAsJsonArray();

        System.out.println ( "Printing result elements" );
        for( JsonElement property : jsonArray)
        {
            System.out.println ( property.getAsString ( ));
        }
        System.out.println (  );


        StagingUser user = new StagingUser ( );
        user.setHi ( jsonArray.get ( 0 ).getAsString ( ) );
        user.setName ( jsonArray.get ( 1 ).getAsString ( ) );
        user.setLastName ( jsonArray.get ( 2 ).getAsString ( ) );

        System.out.println ( "Printing POJO: " );
        System.out.println ( user.toString ( ) );
    }

}
```

### Output:

> **Printing JSON String**
>
> { "d": { "result" : [ "hello", "Frank", "Provost" ] } }
>
> **Printing result elements**
>
> hello
>
> Frank
>
> Provost
>
> **Printing POJO:**
>
> StagingUser [hi=hello, name=Frank, lastName=Provost]

Comment: Thanks a lot! marked as correct for most detailed descrption and examples

Answer (score 2):

Here is the parsing logic for `json` string:

```
JsonParser parser =  new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse("YOUR_STRING");
JsonObject jsonObj = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject d = jsonObj.get("d").getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray result =  d.get("result").getAsJsonArray();
Gson gson = new Gson();
for(int x = 0; x < result.size(); x++){
    JsonObject userOb = result.get(x).getAsJsonObject();
    User userObject = gson.fromJson( userOb , User.class);
}
```

Here,`User` is your class. You need to add `com.google.gson` library to run above code.

Comment: Thanks, can you add how to continue with the result? How will I end up with actual objects of my class?

Comment: @FrankProvost: I have updated the answer. `userObject` will be actual object of your class.

Answer (score 1):

```
String jsonString = "{\"d\": {\"result\": [{\"firstname\": \"bob\", \"lastname\":\"boblast\"}, {\"firstname\": \"alice\", \"lastname\": \"alicelast\"}]}}";

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
System.out.println("JSONOBJECT: "+jsonObject);

JSONObject dObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("d");
System.out.println("RESULTOBJECT: "+dObject);

JSONArray jsonArray = dObject.getJSONArray("result");

System.out.println("JSONARRAY: "+jsonArray);
```

you can get the result as described in above code.

- First get json object of "d".
- Get json object of result.
- get array of result json object.

Answer (score 1):

Use json.jar from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160810) and then

```
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class JsonWalker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JSONObject("{\"d\":{\"result\" :[1,2,3,4]}}").getJSONObject("d").getJSONArray("result").toList().forEach(x->System.out.println(x));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to not spend effort in removing the outer JSON. Just use one of the many JSON frameworks to map it to an object model. Then just extract what you need from the object model and process it further.